# Working with jQuery add row button click - jQuery AJAX PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm trying to call a text box (or a set of div with input fields) with a button click (id: add_row)

The below code works for the first time, but not the second time.

In other words - the add button works and brings the text box for the first time, not the second time. I need the add button to work for 'n' times.

Also is it possible to give dynamic value for input name (i.e percent0, percent1, addr0 and addr1) so that i can post the values to the next page.

Thanks,
Kimz

## Partial Code

```
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#add_row").click(function(){
            $("#addr1").show();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

## HTML Code

```
<table>
    <tr id='addr0'>
        <td><input type="text" name='percent0'  placeholder='Percentage' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='addr1' style="display:none">
        <td><input type="text" name='percent1'  placeholder='Percentage' /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Percentage</a>
```

Here is the full code(JSFIDDLE):
http://jsfiddle.net/4mP9U/1/

Comment: What are you trying to acheive?

Comment: You are only showing the hidden row, which is working perfectly, event is triggered. Problem here is showing n textboxes

Comment: i need a button, which when clicked 'n' number of times should display the text box with id=addr1 . do you understand?

Comment: @Satpal - in other words, the add button, should display the text box. if the add button is clicked 5 times, then i need to show 5 text box one by one(on each click) with different <tr ids>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to add numerous rows to your table, you should create a template, then clone it each time the button is pressed.

http://jsfiddle.net/A8Kyf/

HTML:

```
<table id="container">
    <tr id='addr_template' style="display:none">
        <td>
            <input type="text" name='percent' placeholder='Percentage' />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='addr0'>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name='percent0' placeholder='Percentage' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Percentage</a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 1;
    $("#add_row").click(function () {
        new_elem = $("#addr_template").clone().appendTo("#container tbody").show().attr("id", "addr" + counter);
        counter += 1;
    });
});
```

Comment: wow. this is exactly what i want. please upvote my question. i have selected yours as the answer..

Answer (score 3):

that because you are just showing row on button click.
if you need to add more row than clone that row and append it to table.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#add_row").click(function () {
        var tr = $("#addr1").clone().show();
        jQuery('table').append(tr);
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4mP9U/2/)**

**EDITED**

For unique ID of row and textbox

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr id='addr0'>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name='percent0' placeholder='Percentage' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Percentage</a>
```

**javascript code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#add_row").click(function () {
        var table = jQuery('table');
        var row =  jQuery('tr',table).length;
        var row_id = 'addr'+row;
        var tr = $("#addr0").clone().attr('id',row_id);

        tr.find('input').attr('id','parent'+row);
        jQuery('table').append(tr);
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4mP9U/6/)**

Comment: this is what i want exactly. how about adding the id values so that each text box  have unique id and i need to post the values to next page. please help me rajesh.

Comment: this approach is nice, i need unique id for each text box (i.e name or id) so that i will post all the values in the text box to the next page.

Comment: @Heavy - checked and marked your answer. please check it again. also please upvote my question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve [this](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/xyru8/), use this HTML:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr id='addr0'>
        <td><input type="text" name='percent0'  placeholder='Percentage 0' /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Percentage</a>
```

And this JavaScript code:

```
$("#add_row").click(function(){
    var rowCount = $('#myTable tr').length;
    $('#myTable tr:last').after('<tr id="addr'+rowCount+'"><td><input type="text" name="percent'+rowCount+'"  placeholder="Percentage '+rowCount+'" /></td></tr>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are showing a row with `display:none`.

You can create a row each time your button is pressed.

Demo : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GK9ZG/1/)

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "#add_row", function () {
        var txt = $("input[name=percent0]").clone();
        txt.attr("name", "percent" + $("input[name^=percent]").length);
        var row = $("<tr/>");
        row.attr("id", "addr" + $("tr[id^=addr]").length);
        var cell = $("<td/>");
        cell.html(txt);
        row.append(cell);
        $("table").append(row);
    }); 
});
```